# Can't merge data error with coredata

Tags: cocoa, core-data

I have an app that uses coredata, but when I accidentally open the app 2 times from different locations I get his error message "can't merge data" when trying to close the app.

How can I prevent the other app from opening?
Or is there a way to merge the info?
Thanks,
Jose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core Data lacks concurrency locking so you can't have two apps accessing the same store file at the same time. Core Data isn't a database system but rather an object graph management system that provides the model layer for Model-View-Controller design app. If you try to use it like a database system you will come to grief.

The usually solution to the problem you describe is to create a library directory that contains subdirectories for each instance of the app and put each instance's store in its own dedicated directory so the problem does not occur.

You can build a small server with Core Data that will provide distributed objects to other processes in a reasonably efficient manner. If you have multiple processes that all need the same persistent store, that would be your best bet.

See [Marcus S. Zarra's Core Data book](http://pragprog.com/titles/mzcd/core-data) for an example of how to do this.

Comment: Is there anyway from blocking the 2nd instance from opening?

Comment: By default they won't. You usually have to go out of your way to get an app to launch more than once at a time. If the problem that two different users are opening the same store file, then the solution is to relocate the store file from a system directory to a user's directory so that each user has their own store.